# What does evar0 means and signify in omniture

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

While using Adobe omniture site catalyst we get following tag "eVar0=" in the website where we use some referrer tags. The varibale populate automatically and its not defined in javascript either. I couldn't even find the custom variable at omniture.com website, where variable starts from "evar1 to evar25" and more but no "evar0"

Answer (score 5):

eVar0 (v0) represents your [campaign variable](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/campaign.html). In the javascript implementation, you populate the value in the `s.campaign` variable.

Comment: The link to the campaign variable article is broken.

Comment: @WillLanni looks like document entry was moved to here: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/campaign.html

Comment: Thank you @crayon-violent -- I added the fix, awaiting peer review. :)